# 'Agile' UML diagramming software

Tags: uml, agile

I've tried about 7-8 UML programs from simple to reasonably complex and am yet to find a single piece of software I'm in love with.

Gliffy is the closest to being on the right track. It's limited in features which means nothing gets in the way of just drawing. And it can be integrated with my issue tracker and Wiki too which is great. However it's missing symbols for activity and state diagrams. Plus its connecting process is a bit clumsy.

So I'm also using MagicDraw. It gets pretty diagrams up very quickly with its connection modes. However the program is too much overkill for my use. I just want to type `<<cat>>` in a class box, not define it as a new stereotype in a UML profile first etc... Plus the program takes forever to load up, save etc.

Autodesk Sketchbook and a graphics tablet is nearly good enough and I use it as my whiteboard for tons of things. Quick, however messy of course and moving symbols around and keeping connections is far quicker in vector based drawers.

So I continue my search for UML diagramming software that say an Agile developer would typically use to quickly get up a sketch without having to battle with or be slowed by the tool. No reverse engineering or code generation business, no 'smart' features locking you into standard UML. I know what to draw, I just want a sufficient toolkit to speed that up.

Visio I failed to like within 5 minutes, same with ArgoUML and something by Dusan and some others I tried?

Anyone use something that just doesn't get in the way without having to learn its quirks?

Edit: Windows platform.

Comment: I don't agree that reverse engineering should not be used becuase if the code is changed then all diagrams are lost and you need to redraw them !! I use a merge mechanism which update my diagrams even if the code is refactored. This merge is really easy.

Comment: I use paper and pencil. I learned most of the quirks years ago.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried http://yuml.me/ ? Text driven and super easy. Just right if you don't want to hassle with an overloaded tool.

You just enter:

```
# Cool UML Diagram
[Customer]+1->*[Order]
[Order]++1-items >*[LineItem]
[Order]-0..1>[PaymentMethod]
```

It produces diagram like this:
[image]

Comment: No, I haven't tried it but have seen it a few times on forums like this. Very impressive for illustrating to others or post-documenting but I'm not sure about visually designing on the fly though.

Comment: It's a rails application. Diagrams are nice. But it's a closed source application.

Answer (score 3):

Try [PlantUML](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/demojavascript.html). It's easy to use.

Write the following lines in your favorite text editor:

```
@startuml
class Cat << cat >>
@enduml
```

And run plantuml. You will end up with a nice diagram in the same directory:

[image: PlantUML example]

Comment: I hadn't come across PlantUML but I'm thinking the same as my comment for the yuml post here.

Comment: @stebbo The main advantage of such a text-based tool is that it can be easily put under version control. Now I understand that you don't need sush advantage. So I've posted a different answer, see below.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac, you might want to try OmniGraffle. It'll do your diagrams without any screwing around, but may only support the most common 4 or 5 UML diagram types from memory.

Comment: Ah good point, I'm on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone use something that just doesn't
>   get in the way without having to learn
>   its quirks?

I think you already know the answer: "No, it's not possible."

I used to like JUDE, because the community edition did a nice job.  It's been gutted since they renamed it [Astah](http://astah.change-vision.com/en/product/astah-community.html).

I'll ask another question: Is UML really that important?  It feels like a 90s idea whose day is long gone.  UML and agile don't belong in the same sentence.  It usually means BUFD and standards imposed by architecture groups.

> Autodesk Sketchbook and a graphics
>   tablet is nearly good enough and I use
>   it as my whiteboard for tons of
>   things. Quick, however messy of course
>   and moving symbols around and keeping
>   connections is far quicker in vector
>   based drawers.

I like this solution.  It seems to be more in the spirit of what you want.  Why isn't this adequate?

Comment: I can't see it as not being possible, because many things are so close already. Someone never using Gliffy before could knock up a diagram immediately. Mix Gliffy with MagicDraw's connection lines process and more complete symbol set and you've got a winner.

Comment: I agree getting carried away in UML and standard compliance is a total distraction. But I find the basics of UML fine for diagramming I only do quick sketch diagrams to better visualize a task, typically attach it to the feature/issue in the tracker and really never look at it again. 
Or is there an alternate diagramming notation that Agilists prefer?

Comment: Sketchbook is great in that you don't run out of whiteboard, and saves the camera snapshot and import process. I just find computer type quicker to read at a glance than my handwriting plus moving things around or expanding boxes to fit to insert some more text takes more time than I'd wish.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java then the XMI to Java IDs mapping is important.

Concerning your "cat" free text in the diagram please don't forget that in UML you have 2 level of customization. You can either use a free text in front of the name of the class or a stereotypes. This option is usually called Keyword. Concerning the stereotype it requires the creation of a profile which has its own rules. A 'cat' keyword is better for your example.

Comment: This Omondo could have promise although I don't use Java that much and never plan to go near Eclipse again (if it requires it, I don't know yet). I'll explore it during the week.

Comment: Re: free text/stereotypes, it's the formality of strict UML that I try to avoid. On a whiteboard I can draw guillemets without restriction, that's what I'm after in a UML diagramming tool.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Gaphor](http://gaphor.sourceforge.net/) ? When using UMLasSketch, Gaphor is useful since it allows you to mix elements from different kinds of diagrams in the same model

Comment: I'll have a play with it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might seem nutty, but have you tried using [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com) recently? 
The diagram symbols and connectors in a Google Drawing work really well - seems to work much more like "the way I think" compared to Visio.

Plus you have the benefit of it being stored and shareable online with simple URLs.

Comment: I had a quick play but no, way too slow compared to what to a pixel based sketching program. But thanks for pointing it out, it could come in handy for some other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a visual modeling tool, try [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best modeling tool (for UML, E-R, BPM, etc.) is Sybase PowerDesigner, but is expensive (thousand of dollars range licenses).

A more cheap alternative is Sparx Enterprise Architect.

Comment: Way too complex--just after simple diagramming Nestor.

Comment: I'm making a tool for "easy" diagramming, some day I hope to support UML, but for this year my focus is concept mapping.